# Can't get the right answer while finding angle in C#

Tags: c#, math

I am doing this Introduction To Unity course from coursera. I have reached at first programming assignment which is to find the hypotenuse and angle of two points. I almost got the code right but a few answers are right and a few are wrong! I don't know what is wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProgrammingAssignment1
{
    // IMPORTANT: Only add code in the section
    // indicated below. The code I've provided
    // makes your solution work with the 
    // automated grader on Coursera

    /// <summary>
    /// Programming Assignment 1
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        // x and y coordinates for points
        static float point1X;
        static float point1Y;
        static float point2X;
        static float point2Y;

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates angle and distance between two points
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">command-line args</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // loop while there's more input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input[0] != 'q')
            {
                // extract point coordinates from string
                GetInputValuesFromString(input);

                // Add your code between this comment
                // and the comment below. You can of
                // course add more space between the
                // comments as needed
                
                float deltaX = point1X - point2X;
                float deltaY = point1Y - point2Y;

                float hypotenuse = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.Pow(deltaY, 2));

                float angleInRadians = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
                float angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * 180 / (float)Math.PI - 180;
            

                Console.WriteLine(hypotenuse + " " + angleInDegrees);

                // Don't add or modify any code below
                // this comment
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts point coordinates from the given input string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">input string</param>
        static void GetInputValuesFromString(string input)
        {
            // extract point 1 x
            int spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 1 y
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point1Y = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // move along string and extract point 2 x
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            spaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
            point2X = float.Parse(input.Substring(0, spaceIndex));

            // point 2 y is the rest of the string
            input = input.Substring(spaceIndex + 1);
            point2Y = float.Parse(input);

            #region Unfortunately, Mono doesn't have a Split method!
            //string[] values = input.Split(' ');
            //point1X = float.Parse(values[0]);
            //point1Y = float.Parse(values[1]);
            //point2X = float.Parse(values[2]);
            //point2Y = float.Parse(values[3]);
            #endregion

        }
    }
}
```

You can see the code I added after the Add Your Code comment, so I have succeeded in finding the hypotenuse correctly but angle is where I am going wrong!

```
float angleInRadians = (float)Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
float angleInDegrees = angleInRadians * 180 / (float)Math.PI - 180;
```

These are the two lines to find the angles. So when I input points 5 5 4 4 it gives me correct angle with  Math.PI - 180 in the second line but at the same time when I input 2 2 4 4 it gives me wrong answer.

So I played with it for a while and added Math.PI + 180, so this time I got the right angle for 2 2 4 4 and wrong answer for 5 5 4 4. I just don't know where I am going wrong!

Some help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected result, and what is the actual result you are getting?

Comment: How exactly is this related to Unity3d ... ?

Comment: See TonyMkenu's answer. Check the documentation for Math.Atan2(value), which I suspect will yield a surprise for you about how it handles positive and negative X and Y values passed in as arguments. Oftentimes people create reusable functions such as  degreesToRadians() and degreesToRadians(). Having separate functions would also make it easier for you to test what happens for angles from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: @derHugo Never said the program is related to unity, just said Im doing this course

Comment: @Rethunk thanks, will definitely look out!

Comment: @JonasH bit.ly/2ZTkccb check it out

Comment: If you are planning on doing more work with angles I would highly recommend making an angle-struct with all the code to convert between radians/degrees and normalization (i.e. ensuring the result is between 0 and 360) etc. That way you should never have to think "does this method take radians or degrees".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//radians into degrees
var angle = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) + 360) % 360;
```

Comment: Thanks the formula worked, I tweaked it a bit and added -180 in the end and got the right answers!